# Binding to URL parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following route:

```
this.resource('activities', { path: '/activities' }, function() {
    this.route('on_date', {path: '/:user_id/:on_date'});
});
```

And I'd like to be able to have easy access to the variables :user and :on_date in my router and controller. I *have* figured out a way to get access to this but it's very much a hack. In my controller I can do this:

```
App.ActivitiesByDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var params = this.router.location.location.hash.split('/');
        // note: location hash is api/activities/:user_id/:on_date
        return App.Activity.find({id:params[2], on_date: params[3]});
    },
});
```

While I'm happy this works, it's clearly not a good solution. Any pointers to achieving what must be a pretty common use-case would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature to retrieve directly params on dynamic models.

```
App.ActivitiesByDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Activity.find({params.user_id, params.on_date});
    }
});
```

It should work.

ref : http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models

Comment: Yup that's what I was missing. I should have mentioned that at times I suffer from "right-in-front-of-your-face" syndrome. The doctors say it's incurable but thankfully there are generous people such as yourself that make the symptoms more bearable.